# What Atari system does this 1980s PCB go to?

Tags: hardware-identification

I found this in a bin of parts. The PCB can be identified as an Atari board but does not identify the product.

The board is labeled "ATARI Innovative leisure" and has a copyright date of 1980. It is also labeled "CO15519 REV 8".

Can anyone identify what it's from and whether this layout is identical to a particular revision?

[image: Picture of obverse of unidentified Atari circuit board]

[image: Picture of reverse of unidentified Atari circuit board]

[image: Lower left detail of obverse]

[image: Upper right detail of obverse]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this would have been in an [Atari CX-2600A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_2600_hardware#CX2600-A) On page 1-6 of [this field service manual](https://console5.com/techwiki/images/e/ec/2600_Field_Service_Manual.pdf), there is this image with the caption "2600A Board Layout (Revs 1-13)":

[image: board]

Since that is a revision 8 board, it should have been in one of these systems (and also likely to be nearly identical to revisions 1-7 and 9-13).  You can tell it was for a four switch console by counting the number of "S20X" components.  These would have been the actual switches on the outside of the console, and you can see there are four:

- S201: Power (far left of board)
- S202: Game Reset (far right)
- S203: Game Selector (middle right)
- S204: T.V. Type/Color Selector (middle left)

The manual also states:

> The major difference between the newer single board VCS (2600A) and the original
> VCS (2600) is that all of the components formerly on the switchboard are now located
> on the motherboard (See Figure 1-5). This includes the player control function
> switches (Power ON/OFF, COLOR/SW, GAME SELECT and GAME RESET), RF
> modulator and power supply circuitry. The single board design eliminates the need for the ribbon cable, which connected the switchboard to the motherboard on the 2600
> vcs.

Notice how it makes remarks to the switches being on the motherboard now instead of a separate switch board.

Probably the biggest giveaway though is this parts list in the manual:

[image: Parts list]

The "CO15519" number is the part number for the motherboard, and at the top of page it states "CX2600A Domestic (M/N) VCS".

Comment: Also the CX-2600A was released in 1980, aligning with the copyright date.